# Convert Number into Japanese Words in App Inventor (Spell the number)

Tags: app-inventor

I am creating an Spell Number app using MIT App Inventor 2.
How can I convert the random number generated into words (Japanese)?
Or, not need to be Japanese, but number into words, and can be represented with M(Million), T(Thousands), H(Hundred) etc.

random number generated: 156722000
Expected results (1) : 一億五千六百七十二万二千
Expected results (2) : 1億5千6百72万2千

either is fine.

Comment: The conversion from 156722000 to get 1 B 5 T 6 H 72 M 2 T is not clear to me.

Comment: Sorry for unclear. This just mean that those words will be represented in alphabet, for example B =billions M=Millions T=thousands H=hundreds.

But I guess it is different between japanese and english when spelling the number, so I will delete this expected results. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to keep a file that contains mappings such as below. Then when app starts, read the key-value from the file and store into memory. Next, for each random number, just lookup the number. Another approach is to store these mappings into TinyDB and then for lookup, just use GetValue in TinyDB

1=一億五千六百七十二万二千
2=1億5千6百72万2千